# Dataframe get value for a column with other column in same df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

have a df with values

```
   a        name         hash_name

1234        mark          5678  
5678        cooper        8888
8888        lenoard       1234
```

value for `hash` is present in table `a` and name is also associated with it, hash value should be replaced with `name` like this

```
   a        name         hash_name

1234        mark          cooper  
5678        cooper        lenoard
8888        lenoard       mark
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` with index by `a` column:

```
df['hash_name'] = df['hash_name'].map(df.set_index('a')['name'])
print (df)
      a     name hash_name
0  1234     mark    cooper
1  5678   cooper   lenoard
2  8888  lenoard      mark
```